# WebGL supported but equirectangular panorama example from Three.js not working on device?

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile, three.js

Looking at the [WebGL equirectangular panorama example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_panorama_equirectangular) it works great on desktop and mobile (Samsung S4 Android 4.4.2) with latest version mobile Chrome.

However on the Samsung tablet SM-T230 also with Android 4.4.2 and latest version mobile Chrome the equirectangular panorama example does not work. Here also the [device orientation control example](http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_deviceorientation) does not work.

The only thing that mildly works on this device is the [Canvas geometry panorama example](http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_geometry_panorama) and to my surprise the [CSS3D panorama example](http://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_panorama) works BEST!

So all this leaves me confused. The tablet does support WebGL but not certain parts of it work, like the Canvas geometry panorama example, even if not fluid and barely, but it supports it.

How can I find out if a device supports WebGL equirectangular panorama example or not? I am looking for a way to create a fallback for devices like the Samsung tablet SM-T230 where I would love to use the CSS3D version of the equirectangular panorama.

Now I have found many questions and answers on checking for WebGL support, Three.js even has a Detector.js that helps with this, but how can I find out if a particular device is going to love the equirectangular panorama part of WebGL?

Do I perhaps with Modernizr need to check for other certain sensors that a device needs to have to support the device orientation control example?

My aim is to have an equirectangular panorama with device orientation controls on PDAs that support it, on PDAs that don't use the CSS3D version panorama and on desktops the normal WebGL equirectangular panorama with mouse drag to see various parts of the spherical projection.

I think simply checking if WebGL is supported with Detector.js is not enough here. What else from the code but also from the hardware side would I need to take into consideration please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[An Introduction to the Device Orientation API](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-device-orientation-api--cms-21067)

[DeviceOrientation Event Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/orientation-event/)

[WebGL - 3D Canvas graphics](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webgl)

This solved my question. It was indeed the case that the T230 did not support the DeviceOrientationEvent including its 4 properties alpha, beta, gamma and absolute. In [the test](http://www.audero.it/demo/device-orientation-api-demo.html) these are null and false. So I can use that to check for support and use CSS3D as a fallback where DeviceOrientationEvent is not supported.